# Django and Aptana Studio

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to try out Django Framework, and I wish to do so using Aptana Studio which has PyDev support and basically supports for Google App Engine Projects too.

I have setup Django 1.8.4 using [their official site](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/)

From Aptana Studio, I have configured my Python interpreter too. Then, at creating new project, I could see this too;

[image]

I select 'PyDev Django Project', I add a project name too in here;

[image]

This was supposed to allow me choose from available options of 'Add Project Directory to PYTHONPATH' and so forth (isn't it?)

But then I get stuck here without any option to click on 'Next' or 'Finish' button.

What did I do wrong? Did I miss some steps here?

Comment: have you got Django installed?

Comment: @wobbily_col absolutely yes.

Comment: Did you configure a python interpreter in Aptana? You need to do that before proceeding.

Comment: Oh yes. I have configured python interpreter listed under PyDev inside Aptana @wobbily_col. If not, I would have got a screen asking me to configure Django first. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The solutions was:

1. When you create a new project, Aptana doesn't know if Django is installed, so you must select the option Create links to existing sources:

[image: Create links to existing sources]

2. Click next and include the folder where Django is installed, for me:
   c:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\

[image: include the folder where Django is installed]

3. Click next and complete the options. I'm using Django 1.8 and MySql, so I selected 1.4 or letter and mysql as Database engine:
4. Click finish

Answer (score 0):

I came across this solution while attempting to setup Aptana (Mac, El Capitan) with Python 3.5 and Django 1.10.  I found I did not have to create links if I just added the Django folder to the path.  Click "Add New" then navigated to the Django folder and clicked "Apply".
[View Setting Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCT9S.png)